# How to handle API keys with XCode 8 and multiple developers

Tags: ios, version-control, xcode8

I have two developers working off the same codebase, I'm trying to have each dev have their own API keys both outside version control. The issue I'm running into is this:

Dev 1 adds a config file called configActual.plist, has configActual.plist on the .gitignore, commits and pushes.

Dev 2 clones the project and sees that the configActual.plist is red since xcode can find the file. Dev 2 can't just add the file because now XCode won't compile since it cannot find the original file. Even if Dev 2 forces their own file in and removes the old reference, this just adds a new record to the pbxproj, putting each dev forever out of sync.

Ultimately how do I hide a file from version control while still allowing XCode to find the local version which is outside version control?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a specific version of the "missing" file through finder, then XCode recognized the new file under the old reference. It turns from red to black.